# Can I use $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ to rewrite $9\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ as $9\cos(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve for $x$ in
$$\sin(x) = 3\cos(x)$$

So I did the following:
$$\begin{align}
\sin(x) &= 3\cos(x) \\[4pt]
\sin^2(x) &= 9\cos^2(x) &\text{(squaring both sides)}\\[4pt]
0 &= 9\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x) &\text{(subtracting $\sin^2(x)$)}
\end{align}$$

**My question is:** Am I allowed to use the identity 
$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$$ 
in the equation to make it 
$$0 = 9\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\quad\to\quad 0 = 9\cos(2x)$$

or is that the case that 
$$9\cos(2x)\neq 9\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$ 
because the $9$ is multiplying the $\cos$ only, so that I'm not allowed to use this identity?

Comment: What is X w.r.t. x?

Comment: formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Bernard x is the varible we need to find its value

Comment: Then write it in lowercase as all other occurrences.

Comment: You are allowed to use the identity all you want, but you are not allowed to break "order of operations" (BIDMAS, PEMDAS etc.) rules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations . True, $9$ will only multiply $cos$.

Comment: The notation `\^2` is very obscure. I recommend not to use it at all here. If that notation means that you square both sides of the equation to get the next equation, then write, "Squaring both sides of the equation, the result is".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: once squared, you can use the identity:
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
To obtain
$$\sin^2(x)=9\cos^2(x)=9\cdot(1-\sin^2(x)).$$
From here you get
$$\sin^2(x)=9/10$$
And you can finish the calculation...

There is no need to use the double-angle identity

Comment: hmm... I dont sure what have you done here, can you explain?

Comment: I started from $\sin^2(x)=9\cos^2(x)$ which you obtained and used that $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ to get an equation for $\sin^2(x)$

Comment: ok I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer that helps with the trigonometry. I am responding to this direct question.

> Am I allowed to use the identity  ... because the 9 is multiplying the cos only, so that I'm not allowed to
>   use this identity?

You are right to be worried. You can't, because that violates the distributive law. You know perfectly well that
$$
a(b+c) = ab + ac \ne ab + c .
$$

You just forgot that elementary fact while focusing on the trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos x=0$ is not a solution, we have that

$$\sin x = 3\cos x\implies \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 3\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}\implies \tan x = 3$$

and therefore

$$x=\arctan 3 +k\pi$$